# WebRTC Screensharing 2650x1600 latency and freezes

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, live

In my WebRTC one-to-many room I've started screensharing via Google Chrome browser extension.

The mouse cursor and the image are displayed with a low frame rate in player window. Also, when I move the cursor on the screen it has some lags and friezes.

Is it about my screen resolution? 2650x1600? Why it happens?

- Extension: https://tg-go.noyes.in/i/BQADAgADbQAD4yAYSAqdt16p76BfAg/3b04e02da2ac0c7e89958d00144e2ef9/1502017683
- Video of the lags: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oqJEZiEPAw
- Where you can test it: live.rocketnet.pro:8443/?stream=a

Comment: It's a combination of your screen resolution and your internet connections. Overall, watching your video, the latency is not that bad. Pretty normal.

Comment: Link to my extension: https://yadi.sk/d/W1rL_eEM3LuWeU

Comment: Hey! Did you solve that issue?